# Mean issue in R

Tags: r, mean

I have a column in a dataframe and I am trying to find the mean.  I used:

```
mean(dat$Age, na.rm=TRUE)
```

and got an error that the numeric or logical operator wrong.  Realizing there was a non numeric value, I fixed it using:

```
dat[10, 2] #- value in Age column on row 10
```

I tried it again and still got the numeric error.

Edit: I need to define the function as a new variable.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example - [please see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: If it is a nonumeric, then after assigning you need `as.numeric(dat$Age)`  BTW, if there is non-numeric variable, you don't need to assign to any value, by default `as.numeric` gets `NA` for that i.e. `mean(as.numeric(dat$Age), na.rm = TRUE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By doing the assignment to a value, it just replaces the value corresponding to it.  But, it won't change the column type.  We need

```
dat$Age <- as.numeric(dat$Age)
```

---

Also, as commented above, by doing `as.numeric(dat$Age)` directly on a column with non-numeric elements,  there will be a warning that fills `NA` for non-numeric elements and it can be identified with `is.na`

```
i1 <- is.na(dat$Age)
```

Another approach without warning to identify the rows that are non-numeric would be with `grepl`.  Using the pattern to match either negative (`-`) or other numbers including decimal from start (`^`) to end (`$`) would cover most cases.

```
i1 <- !grepl("^-?[0-9.]+$", dat$Age)

mean(dat$Age, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: So I did as.numeric and looks like it cleared up the issue. But when it prints, it shows a bunch of numbers that are not the ones in the dataset.

Comment: @JackArmstrong  That is because your column is `factor`.  You need `as.numeric(as.character(dat$Age))`

Comment: @JackArmstrong  By default `read.csv/read.table` reads data with non-numeric columns as `factor` class unless you specified in the `colClasses` or used `stringAsFactors = FALSE`.  If you have created data with `data.frame`, default option is `stringsAsFactors = TRUE`\

Comment: so even though you change the value in a cell it defults as non numeric column. That makes sense. I had another numeric column and it worked fine before, but very confusing for a beginner.

Comment: @JackArmstrong  I think you may need to use `read_csv` or `read_table` from `readr` or `fread` from `data.table` which is by default `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`

Comment: @JackArmstrong  I make a point to look at the structure of the dataset before doing anything else.  Because, it gives info about all these problems and avoid spending more time.

Comment: @JackArmstrong  Yes, I think so.  If you need to change the default behavior, change it tin `col_types`

Comment: @JackArmstrong  Check the output `read_csv("x,y,z\n1,2,a\n3,4,b")` and the factor type abbreviation is not mentioned in the documentation, but you can specify it with `col_factor`

Answer (score 2):

You may try casting your input vector to numeric before taking the mean.  This will result in non numeric values getting assigned `NA`, which you may then remove in your call to `mean` using `na.rm=TRUE`:

```
x <- c(1, 'Hello', 3)
mean(as.numeric(x), na.rm=TRUE)

[1] 2
```

This will generate a warning message, but at least it will run.

As a general comment, it is best practice to not mix numeric and non numeric data in the same vector, column, etc.

Comment: is there a way I can return the non-numeric values to identify where the problems come from?

Comment: @JackArmstrong You may use `grepl` in this case, see Arun's answer below.  But, I think that `as.numeric` will do a better job of flagging non numeric data than a regex which we write.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
  x = c(1,2,3,"xxx");
  grepl("[[:digit:]]", x)
```